# Recursively Finding Child elements in javascript array

Tags: javascript

I want to extract child elements from the list below for particular parent node.
These elements will be in ascending order.

```
arr = [
    '1',
    '1.1',
    '2',
    '2.1',
    '2.2',
    '2.3',
    '2.4',
    '3',
    '3.1',
    '3.2',
    '3.2.1',
    '3.2.2',
    '3.3',
    '3.4',
    '3.5',
    '3.6',
    '3.7',
    '3.7.1',
    '3.7.2'
];
```

I want some thing in this format for each element.

```
parsed = [
    {id: '3', childrens:[
        {id:'3.1', childrens: [] },
        {id:'3.2', childrens: [
            {id:'3.2.1', childrens: [] },
            {id:'3.2.2', childrens: [] }
        ] },
        {id:'3.3', childrens: [] },
        {id:'3.4', childrens: [] },
        {id:'3.5', childrens: [] },
        {id:'3.6', childrens: [] },
        {id:'3.7', childrens: [
            {id:'3.7.1', childrens: [] },
            {id:'3.7.2', childrens: [] }
        ] }
    ]}
];
```

I want to pass this parsed JSON to Tree Grid.
I tried to write a function for it

```
function getChilds (str){

    if(arr[arr.length - 1]+'.' === str)
        return;

    var childs = [];

    var task = new Object();

    for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++ ){
        if( arr[i].localeCompare(str) > 0 ){
            task.id=arr[i];
            childs.push(task);
            tasks.push(task);
            console.log(tasks);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: is the data ordered? did you tried something?

Comment: what did you try? paste the code you have so far

Comment: What have you tried so far? The point of Stack Overflow isn't to have other people do everything for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That’s just a JavaScript array containing JavaScript objects. There is no JSON here.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the given string, split by dot and take the values a path to a nested hash table which keep groups for the same level.

If a new level is found, a new object is created and inserted into the hash table.

As result, you get an array with nested object, which have for all children arrays.

The order of the result set is influenced by the order of the given data.

```js
var data = ['1', '1.1', '2', '2.1', '2.2', '2.3', '2.4', '3', '3.1', '3.2', '3.2.1', '3.2.2', '3.3', '3.4', '3.5', '3.6', '3.7', '3.7.1', '3.7.2'],
    result = function (array) {
        var result = [],
            hash = { _: result };

        array.forEach(function (a) {
            a.split('.').reduce(function (r, k) {
                if (!r[k]) {
                    r[k] = { _: [] };
                    r._.push({ id: a, children: r[k]._ });
                }
                return r[k];
            }, hash);
        });
        return result;
    }(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```